# Vue-Router Duplicate Page

Tags: javascript, router, vue.js

I'm in trouble with vue-router :) I create a simple map for router :

```
module.exports = {
  '/': {
    component: require('./views/home')
  },
  '/auth/login': {
    component: require('./views/auth/login')
  },
  '/auth/register': {
    component: require('./views/auth/register')
  },
  '/resumes': {
    component: require('./views/resumes')
  },
  // 404 NotFound
  '*': {
    component: {
      template: "not found"
    }
  }
};
```

And define router to vue and it works perfectly. My home page js codes :

```
module.exports = {
  inherit: true,
  template: require('./template.html'),
  ready: function() {
    if(this.isLoggedIn)
    this.$route.router.go('/resumes');
  }
};
```

I want to load resumes page if user logged in.
When I use it in any event or with v-link directive, it works normal. 
But if I use it on ready function, it duplicates pages. It calls home page and appends second page on it.

IMG : http://imageshack.com/a/img540/9409/3DK1ZL.jpg

Whats wrong? How can I solve it? I am dealing about 4 days with this problem. Please help me guys.

Comment: It's possible the router isn't initialized when "ready" fires. Have you tried moving that code into a `this.$nextTick()`?

Comment: Not only that, you can try to replate this.$route.router with this.$router and use other lifecycle triggers such as attached http://vuejs.org/api/#attached or router triggers such as activate or data http://vuejs.github.io/vue-router/en/pipeline/activate.html

Answer (score 0):

`this.$route.router.go('/resumes')` has already been removed since Vue 2.0.